# What happened to the other 2 muggers?

Tags: plot-explanation, collateral

When Max is tied to the steering wheel in *Collateral*, he attracts the attention of 4 guys. They walk over to him, and one of the guys pulls a gun on him, stealing his wallet, while another guy gets Vincent's briefcase from the back. Then we see those 2 guys walking away; and Vincent confronts and kills them.

The other 2 guys who originally approached the cab seem to just disappear completely once the one guy pulls the gun on Max. Is this a known editing mistake, or is there a reasonable explanation, or did I just miss something in frame?

Comment: Small correction: the same guy (long hair) pulls the gun and takes the wallet as well as the briefcase.